# Define conditional bounds to Pyomo Var

Tags: python, pyomo

Given the following trivial model:

```
model.WEEKS = Set(initialize = [1,2,3])
model.PRODS = Set(initialize = ['Q24','J24','F24'])

model.volume = Var(model.WEEKS,model.PRODS, within = NonNegativeIntegers)
```

I'd like to set varying bounds for each permutation in `model.volume` depending on the initial character of the second index. Currently, I have achieved this by applying the following constraints to specified subsets:

```
# create subsets
Q_PRODS = Set(within = model.WEEKS * model.PRODS, initialize = [x for x in model.volume if x[1][0]=='Q'])
M_PRODS = Set(within = model.WEEKS * model.PRODS, initialize = [x for x in model.volume if x[1][0]!='Q'])

#define functions
def c1(model, i,j):
    return (25, model.volume[i,j], 60)
model.c1 = Constraint(Q_PRODS, rule = c1)

def c2(model, i,j):
    return (40, model.volume[i,j], 75)
model.c2 = Constraint(M_PRODS, rule = c2)
```

Which correctly outputs the following:

```
2 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=3, Index=c1_index, Active=True
        Key        : Lower : Body          : Upper : Active
        (1, 'Q24') :  25.0 : volume[1,Q24] :  60.0 :   True
        (2, 'Q24') :  25.0 : volume[2,Q24] :  60.0 :   True
        (3, 'Q24') :  25.0 : volume[3,Q24] :  60.0 :   True
    c2 : Size=6, Index=c2_index, Active=True
        Key        : Lower : Body          : Upper : Active
        (1, 'F24') :  40.0 : volume[1,F24] :  75.0 :   True
        (1, 'J24') :  40.0 : volume[1,J24] :  75.0 :   True
        (2, 'F24') :  40.0 : volume[2,F24] :  75.0 :   True
        (2, 'J24') :  40.0 : volume[2,J24] :  75.0 :   True
        (3, 'F24') :  40.0 : volume[3,F24] :  75.0 :   True
        (3, 'J24') :  40.0 : volume[3,J24] :  75.0 :   True
```

However, this seems a little clumsy and I wondered if there is more efficient method that would achieve the same ends? For example, by defining a rule to pass during the creation of `model.volume`?

Comment: There's probably about 5 ways to do this.  What you have is fine, especially if you have other needs for the 2 subsets you created.  Alternatively, you could use the same schema to make dictionaries of low_bound and upper_bound, indexed by product and use those dictionaries (like parameters) in your 2 constraints.  or you could use a function to define the upper/lower bounds when declaring the variables.  At the end of the day, I believe `pyomo` will render the same model for all approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance @AirSquid. Once again, I appreciate you taking the time to respond! I'll stick with this approach for now then if it isn't off the mark, though I'm frustrated I couldn't figure out defining bounds as part of the variable declaration. I'll return to it later and see if I can get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callable to provide limits, if desired.  For most `Pyomo` constructs, it must catch the indexing variables and also have a self-reference to the model.  There are other examples in the dox.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3, 4])

def v_limits(m, i):
    if i%2==0: 
        return (10, 20)
    return (8, 9)

m.X = pyo.Var(m.I, bounds=v_limits)

m.pprint()
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Conditionally return the lb, ub tuples! I'll amend my work as this feels far cleaner than creating multiple constraint functions. Thanks @AirAquid!

Comment: Super.  Realize the *return* is not conditional....  just what is returned is.  you can modify to inspect the index coming in and do whatever you want.  Same outcome as what you are doing now in different (more succinct?) format.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was hoping to achieve!